# Measure space and borel algebra question

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(X, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ be a measure space, with Borel algebra $\mathcal{A}$ and measure $\mu$ defined on $\mathcal{A}$. Let $f$ be a nonnegative extended real valued borel function defined on $X$. Let $B$ be the set in $\mathcal{A}$ defined as follows:
$$
B=\{x\in X: 0<f(x)\}
$$
Show that 
$$
\int_X f(x)\mu \: dx =0 \Rightarrow \mu(B)=0
$$

Now, so far I have thought about this: I prove this by contraposition. Suppose $\mu(B) >0$ then show the integral is positive (we need not consider the negative inequality since these are nonnegative functions).  Also, introduce the following
$$
D_n=\{ x\in X: \frac1n < f(x)\}
$$
so that
$$
B=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty D_n
$$
Using contraposition then, we have that 
$$
0<\mu(B)=\mu\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty D_n\right)=\lim_{n\to 0} \mu(D_n)
$$
This is where I am stumped. I am not even sure if this is right (or in the right direction) so far. If it is then where do I go from here. If not, then any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track.  Assume that $\mu(B) > 0$ then there exists $N$ such that $\mu(D_N) > 0$.

Now we have that $\int_X f(x) d\mu(x) \geq \int_{D_N} f(x) d\mu(x) > \int_{D_N} \frac{1}{N} d\mu(x) > \frac{1}{N} \mu(D_N) > 0$ as needed.

Comment: Thank you so much for closing the proof. Really appreciate it!